# I want to set the fab button so that it changes position to adapt to screen size

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, floating-action-button

My XML fab layout.As the title says I've been struggling with this for a while, cant find any fix online

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="285dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="430dp"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="200dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:elevation="17dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_new" />
```

Comment: can you be more explicit please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this as parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in manifest use this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Hope this helps.